# nuxt.js get data from vuex with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, vuex

```js
computed: {
  msgs_id() {
    return this.$store?.state?.get_dir[`${this.$route.params.id}`]['id']
  }
},

async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  try {
    const direct = await $axios.$get(`/chat/messages/40`)
    return { direct }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

When I type the id 40 manually it returns data, but when I return it from the computed it does not return data

Comment: `/chat/messages/${this.msgs_id}` is not working here? What is the value of the computed in the line just before the axios?

Comment: This is very generic, please provide more context. where is asyncData located? it is a method? where are you loading the vuex data?